# How to select a MOSFET?

Tags: mosfet, component-selection

I'm overwhelmed by all the MOSFETs available.  I'm trying to duplicate the effect of an [SI2302](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1810202111_Guangdong-Hottech-SI2302_C181087.pdf), so an N-channel MOSFET, and specifically one that can be operated by an ESP32 logic level input (I think therefore Vgs(th) < 3.3 V) and can handle a reasonable current (the existing has Id of 2.1 A).

A package of either TO-92 or TO-220 would make it easy to solder into place - there is no space for a SMT device to be added.

I'd love to just hook into the existing component's gate but that's connected to a whole load of other things which I don't want to power from the GPIO.

Can anyone point me in the direction of a component that would suit?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: 1) You could solder wires to the legs of the SOT-23 part. 2) Is it for use at a high frequency?

Comment: On electronic vendor websites, you can select components according to your parameter, like THT, current etc.

Comment: @AndrewMorton Soldering not a problem, it's that the existing supply to the gate of the SOT-23 part is connected to other things that I don't want to feed from the ESP.  It is not for high frequency at all, not even 0.1Hz.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up ordering some [IRF3708](https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/irf3708pbf.pdf)s, largely because they're easier to solder than SI2302, being TO-220 packages.  Another SI2302 would have done the trick, I'm not sure why I was so against using one!